# Microsoft Partner Center API - GET subscriptions for customer fails with error 500

Tags: powershell, content-security-policy, microsoft-partner-center

If I try to retrieve all subscriptions for a customer via Microsoft Partner API, I just get http error 500. We are direct Microsoft Partner, and I can get these subscriptions via `Get-PartnerCustomerSubscription` PowerShell command.

My code looks like this:

```
$CustomerId = "CUSTOMERIDOFCUSTOMERINCSPPORTAL"

$Headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $($PartnerRefreshToken)"
    "Accept" = "application/json"
}

$SubsUri = "https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/v1/customers/$CustomerId/subscriptions"
$SubsUriResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Headers -Uri $SubsUri -Method GET
```

But I only get this generic error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : { "statusCode": 500, "message": "Internal server error", "activityId": "73e5479e-0f8c-4ecd-a26f-055ac17e124c" }
At line:1 char:20
+ ... iResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Headers -Uri $SubsUri -Method ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

I have tried to consult Microsoft API documentation, but I do not find any answers, and I cannot seem to figure out if my request is not formatted correctly.

Comment: [HTTP status code `500`, Internal Server Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) "indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request."
As such, it is a _server_-side error that is - hopefully - _transient_, so simply trying again later may solve the problem.

Comment: I tried again and error persist. I then changed my header to this:

$PartnerAuthHeaders = @{Authorization = ("Bearer  {0}" -f $newPartnerToken.AccessToken) }

And switcing to using the AccessToken instead of the 90 days refreshToken, and now it works :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried again and error persisted. I then changed my header to this:

```
$PartnerAuthHeaders = 
  @{Authorization = ("Bearer {0}" -f $newPartnerToken.AccessToken) }
```

And switching to using the AccessToken instead of the 90 days refreshToken, and now it works.